# Clojure: how to update multiple values in a map

Tags: clojure

I have a map that have multiple counters in it, for example:

```
(def m1 (atom {:counter1 10 :counter2 3 :counter3 11}))
;;;=> {:counter1 10, :counter3 11, :counter2 3}
```

I would like to increase counter2 by one, and reset counter1 and counter3 to zero.

I can not seem to think of a way to do it. The best I have come across is the below function. But, this function does not reset counter1 and counter3 back to zero, it just does not increment them.

```
(swap! m1 (fn [m]
            (merge-with + m {:counter1 0
                             :counter2 1
                             :counter3 0})))
;;;=> {:counter1 10, :counter3 11, :counter2 4}
```

Is it possible to do what I am asking with a single swap!, or do I need to implement with a call to swap! and multiple reset!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or separate the two operations:

```
(swap! m1 #(-> % 
           (update :counter2 inc) 
           (assoc :counter1 0 :counter3 0)))
```

**edit**

In case you are on an < 1.7 Clojure version, use [update-in](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update-in) instead of [update](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update)

Comment: By far the most idiomatic solution. For (waaay) more complicated transformations than this, https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter may be useful.

Comment: Is update a separate function that takes a key and function (in this case inc) as its arguments? And a follow up question, why couldn't we just increment :counter2 in the assoc?

Comment: @sakh1979 i have added update(-in) doc links.  `assoc` only associates the value - it does not take a function. The approach with `assoc` would be basically the same as @TheQuickBrownFox suggested (`s/merge m {/assoc m/`)

Answer (score 5):

Keep it simple! Use a normal `merge` and access `:counter2` again from the map.

```
(swap! m1 (fn [m]
            (merge m {:counter1 0
                      :counter2 (-> m :counter2 inc)
                      :counter3 0})))
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could modify your code to do it, by replacing the `+` inside the `merge-with` with an other function:

```
(defn my-plus [old new] (if (pos? new) (+ new old) 0))
```

I am still thinking about a differnt way to solve it.